How to Pick specific keys from the complete set of array resultant from 'List Rows' connector in power automate
I have a result from 'List Rows' controller from table A.
Now, I want to pick predefined set of specific keys (stored in another table B) from the above result and create a CSV with it.
So, my table B has comma separated fields for the CSV header row basically and table A has the data which needs to be populated against this fields.
Can anyone help me to filter this data?
Table A looks like :
[
  {
    "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.incident",
    "incidentid": "3f1b289fe3-7c1e52361259",
    "NUMBER_TIK": "214",
    "AGEING@OData.Community.Display.V1.AttributeName": "age",
    "AGEING": "56533",
    "STATUS@OData.Community.Display.V1.AttributeName": "statuscode",
    "STATUS": 385080007
  },
  {
    "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.incident",
    "incidentid": "389fe3-7c1e52361259",
    "NUMBER_TIK": "21477",
    "AGEING@OData.Community.Display.V1.AttributeName": "age",
    "AGEING": "533",
    "STATUS@OData.Community.Display.V1.AttributeName": "statuscode",
    "STATUS": 385080004
  }
]

Table B looks like:
[
  {
    "csvtemplate": "STATUS, AGEING, NUMBER_TIK"
  }
]

I want this data:
[
  {
    "STATUS": "385080007",
    "AGEING": "56533",
    "NUMBER_TIK": "214"
  },
  {
    "STATUS": "385080004",
    "AGEING": "533",
    "NUMBER_TIK": "21477"
  }
]

I need to populate selected fields in my CSV using the raw data from Table A.


So you want to inner join two data sets?  Can you whip up an example of both tables A and B and then the expected result?  I think it just needs to be a bit clearer.

@Skin Pls check the updated post. Table A has lot of data and Table B has specific columns which need to be filtered and then saved to create CSV

Can you help @Skin

Yes, but I'm pressed for time tonight.  I may be able to find time tomorrow.

Depending on how many records you're processing from Table A, this may not be quick but it's your best bet without using a custom connector.

Step by step, this is how it works ...
Compose Table A
This is the table A data you provided noting that pasting it directly into the flow means I need to replace any leading @ values to be @@.
You need to change this out for your own data from Dataverse.
Compose Table B
As per the last statement just for Table B.
Initialize Final Data Array
This is a place holder for an eventual, transformed array of data.  Blank for now.
Initialize Table A Item Object
This is a place holder for an object that will contained the transformed data for each Table A item.  Blank for now.
For Each Table A Record
The output from Compose Table A.
Compose Table A Item
This is a simple expression which is item() ... it's handy to store the outer For Each item in a Compose for later retrieval.
Reset Table A Item Object
Set's the Table A Item Object variable to be {}.  This makes way for the next loop.
For Each Table B Record
This is an expression to split up the Table B string so you can loop through.  I'm assuming here that you'll only ever have a single row as your provided.  This is the expression ...
split(first(outputs('Compose_Table_B'))['csvtemplate'], ',')

Compose Table B Item (Field Name)
This trim's the field name you want to pull out and stores it in the Compose for later use.
trim(item())

Compose Table A Item Object (Add Property)
This adds the CSV field name property to the value of the Table A Item Object object.  As the loop moves through each CSV field, you add the property name with the corresponding value from the Table A item using a dynamic property value retrieval approach.
addProperty(variables('Table A Item Object'), outputs('Compose_Table_B_Item_(Field_Name)'), outputs('Compose_Table_A_Item')?[outputs('Compose_Table_B_Item_(Field_Name)')])

Set Table A Item Object
Now feed the result of the last step back into the Table A Item Object variable.
outputs('Compose_Table_A_Item_Object_(Add_Property)')

Append To Final Data Array
This adds Table A Item Object to the final array.
variables('Table A Item Object')

Compose Result
This merely shows you the result.
From here, you can create your CSV file using the data in the Final Data Array variable.

